# Laravel - Faço um action @list pra cada Controller ou um Controller 'listController' recebendo parametros?

Tags: laravel-5, controller

Tenho um painel administrativo com diversas áreas suas listagens de itens de cada tabela própria.
O que é melhor fazer:

Um **action** 'list' para cada **Controller** responsável por cada área:

```
class aController extends Controller{
    public function list(){
    }
}
```

---

```
class bController extends Controller{
    public function list(){
    }
}
```

---

```
class cController extends Controller{
    public function list(){
    }
}
```

Ou fazer um **Controller** 'ListController' recebendo parâmetros:

```
class ListController extends Controller{
    public function index($table){
    }
}
```

O último caso parece resolver o problema de repetições de código, porém não sei se trará problemas futuramente.

Comment: Acho melhor criar um "listar" para cada um, e manter as regras devidamente separadas. Vai gerar mais código, mas tudo vai ficar mais "legível". Ficara mais fazer modificações, ou isolar e resolver futuros problemas.

Comment: Kelvym, pelo seu problema aí eu sugeriria usar um scaffold generator, hein.

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar problemas futuros e seguir o conceito de orientação a objetos, acredito que separar as responsabilidades de cada coisa é a melhor opção. Sabemos que várias coisas possuem listagem. Porem, podem haver diferenças de funcionalidades acompanhadas nas listagens. Um filtro de pesquisa por exemplo que pode ter em uma e não ter em outra. Se você faz apenas um controller e um método você não separa as responsabilidades.

Se você tem uma tabela de `departamentos` e outra de `niveis` de usuários. Teria um DepartamentoController com um método para listagem de departamentos e um NivelController tembém com um método para listagem de níveis. Por fim um model Departamento e outro Nivel.